# How do I find an element in an infinite list using the foldr function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, find, element, fold

I'm trying to create a new implementation of the `elem` function in Haskell using the `foldr` function.

So far I have this:

```
count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Integer
count x (y:ys) = foldl (\counter y -> if y == x then counter + 1 else counter) 0 ys
count _ [] = 0

elem' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem' x (y:ys) = foldr (\i elem-> if (count x (y:ys)) > 0 then True else False) False ys
elem' _ [] = False
```

The `count` function is counting the number of occurances of x (another function I wrote) using `foldl`. This works fine for finite lists, but the problem is that I want to take advantage of the `foldr` lazy computation of an infinite list. If I try to use an infinite list as input the program hangs forever.

Basically I want to "break out" once I find any instance of x in the list and return true, otherwise return false.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, try using `foldr` instead of `foldl`. Though counting an infinite list will always hang. I'm not sure why you would want to use `count` for your `elem` implementation at all?

Comment: You're neither using `i` nor `elem` in that lambda. So what are you folding for at all? Also, if you use a fold, you should not use structural recursion (with pattern matching)

Comment: Try `elem' x = foldr (\el elemInRest -> el == x || elemInRest) false`

Comment: @Bergi, it might save some proving in a dependently typed setting, using inductive lists and lazy naturals, but counting elements of an infinite list makes rather less sense.

Comment: @dfeuer: I knew someone would catch on the "always" :-) Yeah, with lazy Peano numerals it might be applicable, and in proofs anyway for sure, but it doesn't make sense for the OP.

Comment: @Bergi, I see the idea, so you evaluate from right to left and if the current element in the list isn't x, it will recursively evaluate the rest of the list. How does it handle a true case? Sorry if this is obvious I'm very new to functional programming.

Comment: @KarimElsheikh: In fact `foldr` evaluates from left to right as well, only the nesting of operations is different. Don't forget that Haskell is lazy, `elemInRest` is not yet evaluated. So if `x` is found, `true` is just "returned" right away - the `||` doesn't need to peek at its second argument, the rest of the list is never expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the basic skeleton on the `foldr` pattern:

```
elem :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
elem x xs = foldr kons knil xs
```

When `foldr` sees `[]`, it will return knil. Since nothing is an element of the empty list, we conclude that

```
knil = False
```

When `foldr kons False` sees a list `a : as`, it returns `kons a (foldr kons False as)`. We can assume inductively that `foldr kons False as = elem x as`, so we seek to solve for `kons` in

```
elem x (a : as) = kons a (elem x as)
```

I bet you can finish up by coming up with the definition of `kons`. Watch out for Boolean short-circuit behavior to make this efficient and avoid problems with infinite lists.